# DropCrateDatabase Seed method not called

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, ef-code-first, entity-framework-6

I'm trying to use entity framwork code first.
Now I want to fill my database with sample data.
Here is my SampleDataClass:

```
public class SampleData:DropCreateDatabaseAlways<MyContext>
{
    protected override void Seed(MyContext context)
    {
        var products = new List<Product>
        {
            new Product{Name="prod1"},
            new Product{Name="prod2"}
        };

        products.ForEach(i => context.Products.Add(i));
    }
}
```

MyContext class:

```
public class MyContext:DbContext
{
    public MyContext():base("MyCon")
    {
        this.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = true;
    }

    public DbSet<Product> Products { get; set; }
}
```

Conection string class:

```
  <connectionStrings>
    <add name="MyCon" connectionString="Data Source=(localdb)\MSSQLLocalDB;Initial Catalog=DatabaseName;Integrated Security=True;" providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
  </connectionStrings>
```

And I set initializer in Application_Start method:

```
    protected void Application_Start()
    {
        Database.SetInitializer(new Models.SampleData());

        AreaRegistration.RegisterAllAreas();
        RouteConfig.RegisterRoutes(RouteTable.Routes);
    }
```

But nothing happend. 
What is the problem?

Comment: You should initialize a context and access a `DbSet`, f.e. in an action method. That's when the database is created.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**NOTE**

The code below will instruct EF to drop and re-create your database when it deems it necessary. This is VERY destructive ! You should change the `DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges` value, as well as the Configuration initialization to prevent this (the two following line are the the configuration initialization)

```
AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
```

**END NOTE**

In your `Application_start()` you should call something like this

```
Database.SetInitializer(new DropCreateDatabaseIfModelChanges<MyContext>());

using (var context = new MyContext())
{
    new MigrateDatabaseToLatestVersion<MyContext, Configuration>().InitializeDatabase(context);
}
```

with `Configuration` being a class declared in `Migrations\Configuration.cs` which has a definition such as

```
internal sealed class Configuration : DbMigrationsConfiguration<Context>
{
    public Configuration()
    {
        AutomaticMigrationsEnabled = true;
        AutomaticMigrationDataLossAllowed = true;
    }

    protected override void Seed(FoyerRural.Models.Contexts.Context context)
    {
     // Database code
    }
}
```

the `Configuration.cs` file can be generated. To do so, you can folow [this tutorial](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/web-api/overview/data/using-web-api-with-entity-framework/part-3).

TLDR; `Tools --> NuGet Package Manager --> Package Manager Console` and execute `Enable-Migrations`)

Comment: Thanks, that's it. I'v alredy do this with another project. I can't remember what exectly I'v do, but I'm sure I haven't use enable-migration there.
But that's works and it is fine.

Comment: Yeah, there is some extra code that doesn't exactly answer your question because I used an example from one of my projects, so I'm sure that this code works but I didn't test any other set-up ... so I preferred to give you tested than :-)